# Chebyshev Distance With tiles isnt working

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So from The phaser Chebyshev distance Example [Link,](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/tilemap/get-chebyshev-distance) It shows the one Man and the transparency distance.

I tried to expand on the example by having one stationary area and one following the player, code,

```js
function updateMap () {
    var origin = map.getTileAtWorldXY(player.x, player.y);
    var origin2 = map.getTileAtWorldXY(400, 400);

    map.forEachTile(function (tile) {
        var dist = Phaser.Math.Distance.Chebyshev(
            origin.x,
            origin.y,
            tile.x,
            tile.y
        );

        tile.setAlpha(tile.alpha+(1 - 0.05 * dist));
    });

    map.forEachTile(function (tile) {
        var dist1 = Phaser.Math.Distance.Chebyshev(
            origin2.x,
            origin2.y,
            tile.x,
            tile.y
        );

        tile.setAlpha(tile.alpha+(1 - 0.05 * dist1));
    });
}
```

So instead of the two squares I expected, One for the player and one for the stationary light, Instead, I get this

[image: Picture]

Why Does this Happen, And How can i Fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phaser's Chebyshev function works fine. the problem is, that on each run of the `update` function the alpha value of the tiles are increased until it reaches 1 (= 100%), due to the fact, that you are adding the current alpha value in ***both*** loops *(`tile.setAlpha(tile.alpha+(1 - 0.05 * dist))`)*

**The solution is to:**

- set the alpha in the first `forEach`- loop. **without** adding the current alpha value. In my example this would be `tile.setAlpha(1 - 0.09 * dist);`
- And for good measure prevent in the second loop, that the alpha getd negative, with a `Math.max`, in my example `tile.setAlpha(tile.alpha + Math.max(0, (1 - 0.09 * dist)));`

Than it should work, as you expect it.

**Here a small working demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        preload,
        create
    }
};

var player;
var point1 = {x: 60, y: 31};
var point2 = {x: 500, y: 150};

new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload (){
    this.load.image('tiles', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/tilemaps/tiles/catastrophi_tiles_16.png');
    this.load.tilemapCSV('map', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/tilemaps/csv/catastrophi_level2.csv');
}

function create () {
    this.add.text(10, 10, 'Click to change "player" position')
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setDepth(100)
        .setStyle({fontFamily: 'Arial'});
            
    let map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'map', tileWidth: 16, tileHeight: 16 });
    let tileset = map.addTilesetImage('tiles');
    map.createLayer(0, tileset, 0, 0);

    player = this.add.rectangle(point1.x, point1.y, 5, 5, 0xffffff, .5)
                .setOrigin(.5);
    
    updateMap(map);
    
    this.input.on('pointerdown', (pointer) => {
          point1 = pointer;
          player.setPosition(point1.x, point1.y)
          updateMap(map);
    });
    
}

function updateMap (map) {
    let fullLightDistanceInTiles = 3; 
    let originPoint1 = map.getTileAtWorldXY(point1.x, point1.y);
    let originPoint2 = map.getTileAtWorldXY(point2.x, point2.y);

    map.forEachTile(function (tile) {
        var dist = Phaser.Math.Distance.Chebyshev(
            originPoint1.x,
            originPoint1.y,
            tile.x,
            tile.y
        ) ;

        tile.setAlpha(1 - 0.09 * dist);
    });
    

   map.forEachTile(function (tile) {
        var dist = Phaser.Math.Distance.Chebyshev(
            originPoint2.x,
            originPoint2.y,
            tile.x,
            tile.y
        );
        tile.setAlpha(tile.alpha + Math.max(0, (1 - 0.09 * dist)));
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

> **Info:** for performance reasons you should think about using only one `forEach` - loop.